# simple css box behind text not wrapping

Tags: html, css

so i have got a box , with some text in it and i want to highlight the text as shown in the jsfiddle.... unfortuntely I can't seem to change the green box so it has the same padding as the text... can someone help a stupid boy ?

the jsfiddle is here ...

http://jsfiddle.net/2es4bx0o/3/

and here is the css involved (not much really)

```
.border {


  background-color:#8cc63f;
}

.tile-area-main {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 780px;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index : 3000;
  background-color:rgba(37, 34, 104, 0.3);
  border-radius: 25px;

}
.tile-area-main p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 2.4em 0.6em;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color : #000;
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve with the green box, please elaborate.

Comment: the text doesn't start at the absolute left and right of the main box its in , yet the width of the green spans the entire width... i want the green box to be only covering the text that is padded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `margin` instead `padding` for the `.border` element:

```
.border {
    margin: 0 2.4em 0.6em !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2es4bx0o/4/

Comment: how do i give the box a bit extra height and width over the text , padding-top and bottom doesn't seem to work

Comment: Play with `padding` and `margin`, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2es4bx0o/7/